# Disable advancing to next slide on click or keypress

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

In PowerPoint, how do I disable moving to next slide on click or keypress during slide show **programmatically**?

I have found quite a few results in Google, but all of them simply ask me to uncheck that particular option in the Ribbon. I need a VSTO/VBA way of doing this. My slides contain hyperlinks that will handle navigation between slides. I do not want to have other ways of navigation.

Also the following line didn't do the trick for me:

```
Pres.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = PpSlideShowAdvanceMode.ppSlideShowManualAdvance;
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG. Can't believe I found this so quickly. Here's the setting that serves the exact purpose I was looking for:

```
Pres.SlideShowSettings.ShowType = PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeKiosk;
```

This will disable all kinds of keyboard and mouse navigation (including the navigation toolbar that appears at the bottom left during slide show). I am now be able to cruise through the show using my own hyperlinks.